# Where can I find the implementation of TableProvider for parquet files in Spark 3.x

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, parquet

Spark is able to read parquet files that underlie a hive table.

I would like to modify how this works for a bespoke use case. From what I read, I need to provide an implementation of TableProvider (and a few other interfaces). I do not want to write this implementation from scratch, I simply want to tweak the current way spark reads from hive tables and from parquet files. However I am having difficulty working out where the current implementation is of TableProvider for either hive tables or directly for parquet, could someone point me at this?

Further, I cannot find any clear description of how to make a provider available and how to use the provider within pyspark. (I am happy to write the TableProvider in either java or python, everything I see suggests it has to be java).

For reference I am using AWS EMR to provide spark.

Also for reference, initially the parts I will tweak relate to which files will be read rather than how they are read.

I am hoping for qualified class names of the classes I need to copy, and how to tell spark to use my modified copies.

Comment: were you able to implement this? Can you post some pointers / code samples?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [ParquetDataSourceV2](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/v3.4.0/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/execution/datasources/v2/parquet/ParquetDataSourceV2.scala) which extends [FileDataSourceV2](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/v3.4.0/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/execution/datasources/v2/FileDataSourceV2.scala) is registered via [Java SPI](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/sound/SPI-intro.html) in [META-INF/services/org.apache.spark.sql.sources.DataSourceRegister](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/v3.4.0/sql/core/src/main/resources/META-INF/services/org.apache.spark.sql.sources.DataSourceRegister). There are a bunch more items defined in [org/apache/spark/sql/execution/datasources/parquet](https://github.com/apache/spark/tree/v3.4.0/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/execution/datasources/parquet) like ParquetReadSupport and ParquetWriteSupport that you may need on your journey.